# WKWebView embed video keeps playing sound after release

Tags: ios, video, youtube, ios8, wkwebview

I'm implementing a service for playing video files with a webview. I migrated from UIWebView to WKWebView, and trying to play Youtube and Coub videos with it. Almost everything is okay, no crashes in iOS 8, but after WKWebView released and removed from screen, video sound keeps playing for a while (in some cases about 45 seconds).

I can't find the way to stop sound of video. I tried to catch system notifications with a media player, but no success.

Is there any way to stop sound or video in WKWebView?

WKWebview configuration is next:

```
//javascript for configurate video viewport (not full screen)
NSString *jScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=%d, height=%d, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);", (int)VIEW_WIDTH, (int)VIEW_HEIGHT ];

WKUserScript *wkUScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:jScript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
WKUserContentController *wkUController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
[wkUController addUserScript:wkUScript];

WKWebViewConfiguration *config    = [WKWebViewConfiguration new];
config.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = YES;
config.userContentController      = wkUController;

_wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, VIEW_WIDTH, VIEW_HEIGHT) configuration:config];
[_wkWebView setBackgroundColor:RGB(0x0a0a0a)];
[_wkWebView setNavigationDelegate:self];
[self insertSubview:_wkWebView atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can load blank page `[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]`

There is probably better solution though

**UPDATE**: fixed in iOS 8.3

Comment: Looks like that really works! [_wkWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html/>" baseURL:nil];

Comment: Thanks, I found @RomanTruba's comment worked best if called in `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: Issue persists on osx 10.13.6, but hack appears to work, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend stopping video with JS code.
For example

```
let stopVideoScript = "var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video'); for( var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++ ){videos.item(i).pause()}"
self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(stopVideoScript, completionHandler:nil)
```

Comment: Yeah, that stupid problem still seems to come and go from time to time on different versions of iOS. Nice hack though.

Comment: works like a charm, set the url = nil actually caused bugs. this js script fill me perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I had a scenario where I had a video playing on the WKWebView, and below the video, was a list of related videos. If you press one of those related videos, the main video player won't reload the video, even though I had made new load request to the webView with the correct link inside.
The only thing which worked for me was to clear all the webView cache before loading the new video:

```
private func removeWebViewCache(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    
    let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
    dataStore.fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in
        dataStore.removeData(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes(), for: records, completionHandler: completion)
    }
}
```

Then, you just call this function first, and then, when it finishes, call your new load request, or simply do any other action that you need:

```
self.removeWebViewCache { [weak self] in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    //self.loadNewVideo()
    ...
}
```