# Stop wkWebView sound when dismissing containing viewController

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

In my view controller i have a WKWebView which play video with sound

When i dismiss the the view controller using:

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

The video sounf still play.

How can i stop it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WKWebView embed video keeps playing sound after release](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410413/wkwebview-embed-video-keeps-playing-sound-after-release)