# How to detect WKWebView is being closed, from javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, wkwebview

We play streaming audio with javascript that is running in a WKWebView object on iOS. If that WKWebView is destroyed or no longer displayed, the audio will oftentimes continue playing to completion. The only way for the user to stop the audio is to swipe up to get the lock screen playback controls and hit 'pause'.

Is there a way for the javascript in the WKWebView to be notified that it is about to be shut down, so that it can stop playback of the audio before the WKWebView is destroyed?

I've tried hooking into 'pagehide', 'unload', 'beforeunload', and 'visibilitychange' events, with no luck.

I'm sure a custom event could be triggered from the native code, but I don't have control of that side of things. Is there anything else that works?

Answer (score 0):

This bug was apparently fixed in iOS 8.3+, but the suggested answer of loading a blank page as the view disappears works very well and could be useful if supporting apps running on older OS versions. This approach is also much more resilient than relying on each JS implementation running in the WKWebView to stop its own media playback after being notified of the impending 'shutdown' of the web view:

In your WKWebView view controller class' `-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` method, run the following code to load a blank page into your web view. The code assumes your reference to your web view is `self.webView`, thus modify as needed.

`// fix to prevent embedded audio/video from playing once the view has closed...
[self.webView loadHTMLString:@"<html/>" baseURL:nil];`

See [WKWebView embed video keeps playing sound after release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410413/wkwebview-embed-video-keeps-playing-sound-after-release) for more details...